# Perl - How to check if a server is live using Ping?

Tags: perl, tcp, connection, port, ping

I'm using Perl 5, version 30 on Linux. I want to check if a server is alive and I am only interested if the ping call returns true or false. Here's my (non-working) code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Ping;
my $pinger = Net::Ping->new();
if ($pinger->ping('google.com')) {
   print 'alive\n';
} else {
   print 'dead\n';
}
```

The code should work (I think). But **it fails (returns "dead") for every server, every time.** It also fails if I execute as sudo: `sudo perl pingcheck.pl`. (EDIT: **I cannot use sudo** in practice. I tried it only for troubleshooting.)

I do have `Net::Ping` installed:

```
$ cpan -l | grep Net::Ping
Net::Ping       2.71
```

There are no error messages from Perl.

If I do the same in bash, the ping works as expected:

```
$ ping -c 3 google.com
PING google.com (64.233.178.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ol-in-f100.1e100.net (64.233.178.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=49.8 ms
64 bytes from ol-in-f100.1e100.net (64.233.178.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=49.8 ms
64 bytes from ol-in-f100.1e100.net (64.233.178.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=43 time=50.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.754/49.846/50.011/0.116 ms
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ ping -c 3 google.com
```

This is doing an ICMP ping.

```
my $pinger = Net::Ping->new();
if ($pinger->ping('google.com')) { ...
```

This is **NOT** doing an ICMP ping. From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Ping#DESCRIPTION):

> You may choose one of six different protocols to use for the ping. **The "tcp" protocol is the default.** ... With the "tcp" protocol the ping() method attempts to **establish a connection to the remote host's echo port**.

The echo service is today almost never active or the port is blocked, so using this as endpoint will usually not work. If you would do instead an ICMP ping with Net::Ping it works as it does with the `ping` command:

```
my $pinger = Net::Ping->new('icmp');
if ($pinger->ping('google.com')) { ...
```

Note that none of this is really suitable to determine if a host is up. ICMP ping is often blocked. Instead you should check if a connection to the specific service you want to use is possible:

```
# check if a connect to TCP port 443 (https) is possible
my $pinger = Net::Ping->new('tcp');
$pinger->port_number(443); 
if ($pinger->ping('google.com')) { ...
```

Comment: I cannot use the ICMP ping protocol because that requires sudo (from the docs). However, your last option of using a specific TCP port looks interesting. I will try it and I will accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Using TCP and a specific port does work. Answer accepted.